QCombobox disabled state styling
I need to style custom QComboBox's disabled state. For normal state I use stylesheet like that:
"QComboBox {"
    "border: 1px solid grey;" 
    "border-radius: 8px;" 
    "combobox-popup: 0;" 
    "background: transparent;"
    "padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;""}" 

And it works OK.
When I use "QComboBox:disabled{}" stylesheet nothing happens and widget is drawn with usual disabled colors. What should I do?
Here's full widget code(widget is created in Designer):
customdropdown::customdropdown(QWidget *parent) : QComboBox(parent)
{
    this->view()->window()->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint );
    this->view()->window()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    this->setItemDelegate(new Delegate());
    setStyleSheet("QComboBox {"                                 //ComboBox
         "border: 1px solid grey;"
         "border-radius: 8px;"
         "combobox-popup: 0;"
         "background: transparent;"
         "padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;""}"
   "QComboBox QAbstractItemView {"
          "color: black;"
          "border: 1px solid grey;"
          "border-radius: 8px;""}"
    "QListView::item {"
          "height: 26px;""}"
    "QComboBox::down-arrow {"
         "image: url("\":/rsc/img/down_arrow.png\"");""}"
    "QComboBox::drop-down:button {"
          "border: 1px solid grey;"
          "border-radius: 8px;"
          "border-left: none;"
          "background-color: transparent;"
          "width: 30px;""}"
    "QComboBox:disabled{"
          "border: 1px solid red;"
          "border-radius: 8px;"
          "combobox-popup: 0;"
          "background: red;"
          "padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;""}");
}

void Delegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), option.rect.width(), option.rect.height());
    if (index.row() == (index.model()->rowCount()-1))  //if the last item
    {
        path.clear();
        path.addRoundedRect( option.rect, QString("8").toInt(), QString("8").toInt() );
        path.addRect( QRect( (option.rect.x()+option.rect.width()-10), option.rect.y(), 10, 10 ) ); // Top right corner not rounded
        path.addRect( QRect( option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(), 10, 10 ) ); // TOp left corner not rounded
    }
    painter->save();
    painter->setClipping(true);
    painter->setClipPath(path);
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    painter->restore();
}


Please provide a proper [mre]. Also add the output of QApplication::style()::objectName() and test with the more compliant "fusion" style (QApplication::setStyle("fusion")).

Added stylesheet example in my question. I tried to use QApplication::setStyle("fusion") and nothing changed

Please do exactly as asked: that is just the QSS (we need a proper MRE) and report the output of the application style (and before setting any style sheet): the combo style is pointless, since it obviously uses the style sheet style, and we cannot know how the QSS was applied and if the widget inherited other properties set on the parent. Also include accurate OS/Qt versions.

I use Qt 5.15.3 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I can't do exactly as asked since there's "no member named objectName in global namespace". What should I put instead?

I don't know the exact syntax in C++ (the above code was just a [mis]educated guess, as I don't use C++). Just get the style() of the QApplication instance, and then the objectName() of that style, similarly to what you attempted with the combo box. Note that the MRE is quite important, and you should add the version details you wrote above to the question. Since you're probably using a Designer UI, ensure that you attach a proper minimal UI (they are plain text XML files) that allows to reproduce the issue, any other widget should be removed.

I accidentally found the problem. Widget code contains two overrided methods: showPopup() and hidePopup() with their own stylesheets(which don't contain "disabled" section). For some reason these methods are called even if widget haven't been activated and they overwrite the stylesheet. So I just added "disabled" section into all stylesheets. Thanks for your help

That shouldn't happen, as those functions are only called when explicitly needed (mouse/touch press, specific key combinations). Are you sure you didn't accidentally placed a call to those functions somewhere else in your code, maybe for testing reasons or forgotten code? A basic QDebug in those functions should suffice to check about that.

I can't fully understand how it works, but the problem is in the order in which the widgets are initialized after ui->setupUi.
Found two things that can help if your correct stylesheet doesn't work:

custom widget declaration shouldn't be in mainwindow.cpp
widget stylesheet should be applied in some method(NOT in the constructor)

In my case I added initWin() method to my custom widget, moved setStylesheet() into it and then called initWin() from mainwindow(AFTER ui->setupUi) like this: ui->_objectName_->initWin(). If there's several widget you need to style, you can access them with
foreach (auto var, this->findChildren<_className_ *>()) 
    {
        var->initWin();
    }

